# How to loop list in fnmatch

Tags: python, wildcard, glob, fnmatch

I am trying to move files from current directory to directory named 'python' in current directory if they are found in a list called 'file'. With the result that the file named '1245' will remain in same directory. I am trying to use fnmatch to match pattern so that all files that are contain 123 in their name can be moved.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil
list_of_files_in_directory = ['1234', '1245', '1236', 'abc']
file = ['123', 'abc']


for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, file):
        shutil.move(f, 'python')
```

this throws following error:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

```
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, file+'*'):
        shutil.move(f, 'python')
```

this throws following error
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` is a list, you can't pass that as the pattern to `fnmatch`.

I'm guessing you want something like

```
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if any(fnmatch.fnmatch(f, pat+'*') for pat in file):
        shutil.move(f, 'python')
```

though arguably `file` should probably be renamed to something like `patterns`.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Now I want to use a file which contains data (names of files) that can be used as list as in line 5 in the question

```import fnmatch, os, shutil
list_of_files_in_directory = ['1234', '1245', '1236', 'abc']
file = ['123', 'abc']```

How do I use the file as a list (I don't want to put the name of files to be moved in the python code as it would just look bad).

Comment: That seems like a topic for a separate question. As you can see, attempting to post code in comments is basically useless. Do you mean you want to read the patterns from a text file? `with open(filename, "r") as patternfile: patterns = patternfile.readlines()`

Comment: I understand your point. I can't understand code easily here. Ok, I will make a new question.